# Sqlite3 Add new row to the table from user input using C

Tags: c, database, sqlite, user-input

I am trying to modify Sqlite3 database using C. I want to add a new data to the "deals" table which I get from the user input.
This is what I have tried to do but I get errors trying to put user input to the string which I can later on execute.

```
char client[MAX],price[MAX],amount[MAX];
printf ("Please enter client ID: \n");
scanf("%s",client);
printf ("Please enter price ID: \n");
scanf("%s",price);
printf ("Please enter amount in euros: \n");
scanf("%s",amount);
char *sql = "INSERT INTO deals(id_client,id_price,euro_amount) VALUES (%s,%s,%s);",client,price,amount;
sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be binding user supplied values to parameters in a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).

Comment: what do think you the string `char *sql = ...` does?

Comment: @Shawn I'll try, thank you

Comment: @qrdl the string itself does nothing, but it's passed as an argument to the sqlite3_exec() later on

Comment: qrdl means that you just define a `char*` and assign it, but the `%s` is kept verbatim in there, nothing replaces it with your values. You'd need `sprintf` or such for that. That said, when you get errors, add them to your question, so that others can see much faster what's going wrong. See [ask].

Comment: @Robert No, all values but the last one are thrown away, so this line has the same effect as `char *sql = amount;`

Comment: @qrdl Thanks for clarifying. Looks like my C is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a string that contains correct sql statemnt, and one of possible ways to do it is using 'sprintf' function:

```
char sql[1024]; /* make room to hold sql string */

sprintf(sql,"INSERT INTO deals(id_client,id_price,euro_amount)\ 
VALUES (%s,%s, %s);", client,price,amount);
```